# Using a _linear_search helper method inside a linked list method

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove all data = to the key given inside of a linked list.

```
v = 1
    while v == 1:
        p,c,i = self._linear_search(key)
        if i == -1:
            v += 1
        if c is not None:
            p._next = c._next
```

It removes the first value in the list but fails to continue and remove the following data = to the key in the linked list. 
I am curious as to how this does not work, I am calling the helper method to find the key. Once a node is removed, why does it not call to the next node in the list to remove that one???
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Switching the

```
if i == -1:
    v+=1
```

TO

```
elif i == -1:
    v+=1
```

AT THE END OF THE LOOP:

However, Is someone able to use a computational approach to this, as to how the computer read my code.